# Apt output showing unneeded stuff

Tags: apt

Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 LTS x86_64

On every install using apt it will output this, how do i "hide" it? by hiding i mean find the source of this output and uninstall it? or find the package that checks after every run.

```
Scanning processes...
Scanning processor microcode...
Scanning linux images...

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

The processor microcode seems to be up-to-date.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
```

Comment: It's part of the routine / checks apt is running, showing that all is good and no user interaction need. So what bothers you about that specifically?

Comment: Its kind of useless to know and pretty annoying looking at it on every run

Comment: Possible work around is to configured unattended upgrade so you don't need to trigger the package updates yourself.

Comment: any way to do that on ubuntu server?

Comment: get the source code, remove the logs and recompile. Only way.Code is [here](https://github.com/Debian/apt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `apt` doesn't know any options to suppress output to the terminal while running.

You could use `apt-get` instead, which `apt` is build on top on. `apt-get` knows the option `-q` which suppresses most but not all output. The option `--qq` suppresses all output, which is not recommended for all cases, see `man apt-get` for details on that.

Alternatively, you can configure `unattended-upgrades`, which enables systems, especially server systems, to upgrade without user interaction automatically. A step-by-step guide can be found e.g. at the [Digital Ocean community tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-keep-ubuntu-22-04-servers-updated) or at the [Ubuntu community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the thread here, but the package that is doing this is "needrestart". At least on kubuntu it is not installed by default. I noticed this new message after I installed it. So if you installed it, then you can remove it with
`apt remove needrestart`